# Solve: $(3 + \cos2\theta)\frac{dx}{d\theta} = x\sin2\theta$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The variables $x$ and $\theta$ satisfy the differential equation

$$(3 + \cos2\theta)\frac{dx}{d\theta} = x\sin2\theta$$

and it is given that $x = 3$ when $\theta = \frac {\pi} {4}$

Solve the differential equation and obtain an expression for $x$ in terms of $\theta$.

I am stuck in getting all $\theta$'s in one side and $x$'s on the other side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(3 + \cos2\theta)\frac{dx}{d\theta} = x\sin2\theta$$

It's separable, so is, you can have the variables in different sides:

$$\frac 1x\frac{dx}{d\theta}=\frac{\sin 2\theta}{3+\cos 2\theta}$$

$$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{\sin 2\theta}{3+\cos 2\theta}d\theta$$

Now, you have the variables in different sides ready to integrate both sides. Can you continue?

Comment: Thank you!, but how would you integrate the RHS?

Comment: With the variable change $u=\cos 2\theta\to du=-2\sin 2\theta d\theta$, the integral is immediate